# Global method for all Controller classes ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a lot of different *controllers* and each of them contains a lot of *ActionResult methods* which returns different views.

In my program you set a variable before you start using it. I store the variable in a *Session*.

For now, most of my Controllers, have methods with the same *if-sentence*. 
**Example:**

```
        if (Session["myVariable"] == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("/../Cons/SetVariable");
        }
```

What i would like to is not to write this logic in all my controllers methods. Perhaps there is a way i could extend a new controller with the logic or something similar?

I hope somebody understands my problem and can help.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at action filters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use MVC/WebAPI's filter attributes to execute the check and use context to perform the actions

```
public class VariableCheckerValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext 
    filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.HttpContext.Session["myVariable"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("/../Cons/SetVariable"‌, filterContext.RouteData.Values);
        }
    }
}
```

Then register the action filter as a global filter, and it will automatically apply to every single action in your application.

In WebApiConfig (in case of WebAPI project), in typically the `Register` method, add:

```
config.Filters.Add(new VariableCheckerValidationAttribute());
```

Or, instead, apply at controller or action levels as needed.

If you do decide to go the global application, and you have an action that doesn't need it, then you would need to create an attribute to 'exception' out of the policy, and update the above attribute code to test for presence of the 'exception' attribute and then not apply the check in that case.

Comment: No problem. Is there no need to register the `VariableCheckerValidationAttribute` globally?

Comment: @dcg, I was just expanding my answer as you typed your last comment.  Yes if it is to apply globally.  If not, then it can be applied per controller or per action method, like any other validation attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I get an error on the RedirectToAction, saying that the name does not exist in the current context. Is there a special place i should create the VariableCheckerValidationAttribute class?

Comment: @crellee, Oops, forgot that `RedirectToAction` is a helper method on the base controller.  Updated the code (hopefully correctly) where you need to construct `RedirectToRouteResult` yourself (same type that the helper returns).  Check updated answer and see if it works now.

Comment: You are a legend and you have solved my problem. Instead of ValidationAttribute i used ActionFilterAttribute and now it works perfectly. Thank so much for the help!!!!!

Comment: @crellee, Oh, another D'oh! on my part... I meant it to say ActionFilterAttribute - I don't know why my fingers chose to type Validation (probably b/c you're trying to validate something).  Corrected that as well in the post.